# How to use parametized url in express js and nodejs - Not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use delete method in node js. The id of item to delete i must fetched it from the parametized url.

Below is piece of code.

in route:

```
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();


  const articlesCtrl = require('../controllers/articles');
  const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

  router.post('/', auth.verifyToken, articlesCtrl.createArticle);
  router.delete('/:articleId', auth.verifyToken, articlesCtrl.deleteArticle);


  module.exports = router;
```

and in my controller I have the following:

```
   const article = new Article();


   exports.deleteArticle = (req, res, next)=>{
        console.log(req.route);
        article.deleteOne(req.params.articleId)

       .then( ()=>{
           res.status(201).json({
              status: "success",
              data: {
                  message: "Article successfully deleted",
              }
           });
       })

       .catch( (error)=>{
           res.status(404).json({
               status: "error",
               error: "Article could not be deleted.", 
        })
      });
  };
```

My setup for postman is as below.
[image]

Comment: In postman it should be /articles/10, currently you're sending it as a query param not as a param

Comment: and how will I be able to access the articleId , because if I try to log it i get undefined

Comment: It will be undefined because you're sending it in query string which accessible through req.query

Comment: If you want to access to through req.params then send it like i did in answer

Answer (score 0):

In postman URL should be like this -

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles/10
```

Currently you're sending articleId as query param which can be accessible like -

```
req.query.articleId
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `parameters` in your router to pass the articleId, but then using `QueryString` in your postman API call, and that is the problem.

Your postman should be `'.../api/articles/ArticleId'`

Query string and parameters are different. you can read [this](https://stackabuse.com/get-query-strings-and-parameters-in-express-js/) article to understand their difference.